# QT draw a rectangle on top of another when a button is clicked

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

[image]

I am completely new to QT and trying to draw a rectangle when a button is clicked,

The following steps should happen when a button is clicked,
1. when the button is clicked. it should open a popup with a dropdown of colors and user can select one color and click OK then a rectangle with that color should be drawn on the screen.
2. The user can click the button again and another rectangle should be stacked on top of the previous rectangle.

I have written code to create a rectangle when a button is clicked but it is not drawing anything on screen and the following message is thrown.

```
#include "dialog.h"
#include "ui_dialog.h"

#include <QDialog>
#include <QComboBox>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QStringList>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QGraphicsItem>
#include <QGraphicsScene>

Dialog::Dialog(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Dialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

Dialog::~Dialog()
{
    delete ui;
}

class CustomDialog : public QDialog
{
public:
    CustomDialog(const QStringList& items)
    {
        setLayout(new QHBoxLayout());

        box = new QComboBox;
        box->addItems(items);
        layout()->addWidget(box);

        QPushButton* ok = new QPushButton("ok");
        layout()->addWidget(ok);
        connect(ok, &QPushButton::clicked, this, [this]()
        {
           accept();
        });
    }

    QComboBox* combobox() { return box; }

private:
    QComboBox* box;
};

void Dialog::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QStringList itemList({"Red", "Blue", "Green"});
    CustomDialog dialog(itemList);
    if (dialog.exec() == QDialog::Accepted)
    {
        scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
        ui->graphicsView->setScene(scene);
        QBrush redBrush(Qt::red);
        QBrush blackBrush(Qt::black);
        QPen blackpen(Qt::black);
        blackpen.setWidth(3);
        rectangle = scene->addRect(10,10,100,100,blackpen,redBrush);

        rectangle->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable);
    }
}
```

I can now get one rectangle but if i click the button again ,it should add another rectangle.
How to do that.

Comment: Isn't the topic slightly related to your other question? [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40919414/have-a-combobox-inside-a-message-box)

Comment: yes it is.. Can you please help today ?

Comment: 1. Do you want a color picker widget or just some of your predefined colours to be available from the list? How does the user specify where the rectangle is drawn? Click and drag or there is just some static area which should be coloured? 2. What do you mean by stacked? Just drawn over the old one or you need to be able to do smth with the old one afterwards

Comment: 1.I have few predefined colors.
2. Yes I have a predefined area which will be on the mainwindow.
3.No click and drag when I click Ok in the popup button the rectangle of the selected color is drawn on the main window and the next rectangle will be stacked on the top of the old one.
4. The rectangle is clickable as if the user wants he can choose the rectangle and create a new rectangle in between the other two. ( it should be like wooden blocks stacked over each other and you can insert a new one in between the 2 wooden stacks)

Comment: 1. Understood 2-4. If I understand you correctly [QGraphicsScene](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qgraphicsscene.html) might get handy in your case. However it would good if you could show your desired result (the stacked rects) on some image for clarification. The rectangles are movable only programatically (by adding the new rect). The user cannot directly move a rectangle, correct?

Comment: yes absolutely. User cannot move the rectangles. User can just select the rectangle(can show the selected by different border may be?) and add a rectangle on top of it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129660/discussion-between-psdebugger-and-dusteh).

Comment: Any success with the proposed approach?

Comment: Not really. I tried my best but still not able to draw multiple rectangles on click of a button

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have more rectangles than the one you already can draw and you want to make some interactions to them you need to do two things.

First you need to have a way to access all the rectangles in the scene. You can do this using `QGraphicsScene::items` method which will give you a list of `QGraphicsItem` objects (convertible to the `QGraphicsRectItem`).

I'm not sure if in your case the actual rectangle dimensions will be constant or they should adjust each time a rectangle is added. Either way since you can access their collection you can iterate through the items and adjust their sizes and positions how you like.

As to the rectangle selection to know where to add the new shape you should look into the `QGraphicsScene` signal called [focusItemChanged](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscene.html#focusItemChanged) or to a method [focusItem](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscene.html#focusItem). In your case I would go with the latter one.

```
QGraphicsItem *QGraphicsScene::focusItem() const
```

You should call this method in your `on_pushButton_clicked()` slot implementation. It gives you the currently selected shape in the scene. You can simply cast the `QGraphicsItem*` to `QGraphicsRectItem*` to read position and size of the object in the scene.

Hope this helps.