# Have a combobox inside a message box

Tags: c++, qt, combobox

I want to create a combobox inside a message box and return the selected value to be used later.

I can do the same on the window itself but not sure how to do that inside a combobox.

```
    MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->comboBox->addItem("Red");
    ui->comboBox->addItem("Blue");
    ui->comboBox->addItem("Green");
    ui->comboBox->addItem("Yellow");
    ui->comboBox->addItem("Pink");
    ui->comboBox->addItem("Purple");
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
       QMessageBox::about(this,"Choose color of rectangle", ui->comboBox->currentText() );
}
```

Comment: It isn't easier to just make an editable combobox?

Comment: I want to make that combobox appear when the button is clicked, not on the mainwindow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correct you would like to show a combobox in a separate dialog window for the user to select some option.

One of the ways to do that, would be to subclass `QDialog`. If a combo field and a button to accept is sufficient the class could look as below:

```
class CustomDialog : public QDialog
{
public:
    CustomDialog(const QStringList& items)
    {
        setLayout(new QHBoxLayout());

        box = new QComboBox;
        box->addItems(items);
        layout()->addWidget(box);

        QPushButton* ok = new QPushButton("ok");
        layout()->addWidget(ok);
        connect(ok, &QPushButton::clicked, this, [this]()
        {
           accept();
        });
    }

    QComboBox* comboBox() { return box; }

private:
    QComboBox* box;
};
```

To use the class object you can call `exec` to display it modally. Then you can verify whether the user accepted the choice by pressing the `ok` button and take proper action.

```
QStringList itemList({"item1", "item2", "item3"});
CustomDialog dialog(itemList);
if (dialog.exec() == QDialog::Accepted)
{
    // take proper action here
    qDebug() << dialog.comboBox()->currentText();
}
```

Similar approach is implemented in the `QMessageBox` class where a number of options can be specified to alter the displayed contents (for example button configuration or check box existance).

**EDIT:**
To use the sample code in your own project you should put the latter section I posted into your `on_pushButton_clicked()` slot. Substitute the `itemList` with your color names list. Then put the `CustomDialog`  class to a separate file which you include in main and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks Dusteh, What i am looking for is. the button is on the mainwindow and when it is clicked popup/ Dialog is opened and it has combobox

Comment: Then the above applies. One more thing you need is to place a button in your `MainWindow` and connect its clicked() signal with a slot where the CustomDialog is created and displayed. Am I correct?

Comment: i guess yes. I already have a button in the mainwindow but I am not sure what to put inside the on_pushButton_clicked() .. and where to put your code in the project. Can you please help with that too.

Comment: C:\QT Test\Combobox\dialog.cpp:21: error: expected type-specifier before 'QHBoxLayout'
         setLayout(new QHBoxLayout());
                       ^

Comment: Be sure to include proper headers: QDialog, QComboBox, etc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129585/discussion-between-psdebugger-and-dusteh).

Comment: Sure we can do that but at some other time, it was already past midnight for me