# QT- choose color from combobox and draw rectangle

Tags: c++, qt, combobox

I want to choose the color from the dropdown and based on that color I want to draw a rectangle on the window.
I can draw a rectangle with predefined color but not sure how can I pass the color from the combobox.
and Only one rectangle is drawn on the window, I want to draw multiple rectangles on the window.

So the procedure works like this. User will click the push button --> combobox appears ---> choose the color --> click OK and rectangle of that color will appear on the window.

Dialog.cpp

```
    Dialog::Dialog(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Dialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

Dialog::~Dialog()
{
    delete ui;
}

class CustomDialog : public QDialog
{
public:
    CustomDialog(const QStringList& items)
    {
        setLayout(new QHBoxLayout());

        box = new QComboBox;
        box->addItems(items);
        layout()->addWidget(box);
        connect(box, SIGNAL(currentIndexChanged(const QString&)), this, SLOT(colorSelected(const QString&)));
        QPushButton* ok = new QPushButton("ok");
        layout()->addWidget(ok);
        connect(ok, &QPushButton::clicked, this, [this]()
        {
           accept();
        });
    }

    QComboBox* combobox() { return box; }

private:
    QComboBox* box;
};

void Dialog::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QStringList itemList({"Red", "Blue", "Green"});
    CustomDialog dialog(itemList);
   // connect(box, SIGNAL(currentIndexChanged(const QString&)), this, SLOT(colorSelected(const QString&)));
    if (dialog.exec() == QDialog::Accepted)
    {

        scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
        ui->graphicsView->setScene(scene);
        QBrush redBrush(Qt::red);
        QBrush blackBrush(Qt::black);
        QPen blackpen(Qt::black);
        blackpen.setWidth(3);
        rectangle = scene->addRect(10,10,100,100,blackpen,redBrush);
        rectangle->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable);
    }
}

void Dialog::colorSelected(const QString& text)
{
      const QColor selected =  colorMap[text];
}
```

The previous post doesnt solve my question.

Comment: OT: wwWidgets has a nice color chooser combobox. http://www.wysota.eu.org/wwwidgets/ doc: http://www.wysota.eu.org/wwwidgets/doc/html/qwwcolorcombobox.html

Comment: I have my predefined colors which I want to use. I just want to create a rectangle based on the color selected from the dropdown in the QT

Comment: And what is a problem? Get a chosen color from the dialog and use it.

Comment: Yes in my problem I am predefining the color Red and drawing a red color rectangle  but how to use the color from the dropdown and draw a rectangle using that color ?

Comment: And I want to draw multiple rectangles after every click of push button but when I do that previous rectangle disappears

Comment: Possible duplicate of [QT draw a rectangle on top of another when a button is clicked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40918951/qt-draw-a-rectangle-on-top-of-another-when-a-button-is-clicked)

Comment: Didnt get enough answers on that post and did some improvement from my previous post

Comment: Ok, withdrawn the flag

Answer (score 0):

If you are not interested in a color picker and you want your own solution with a`QComboBox` you can predefine your own set of colors you want to use.

You can declare a map, for instance `QMap<QString, QColor> colors;` which would hold the color value under a key which describes it with a string.

Then you should define the desired values. For example:

```
colors = 
{
    {"Red", QColor(255, 0, 0)},
    {"Green", QColor(0, 255, 0)},
    {"Blue", QColor(0, 0, 255)},
};
```

You can easily use this map to fill the contents of your `QComboBox`. That's quick as writing:

```
box->addItems(colors.keys());
```

Next action depends on when you need to know the color value. If you want to know it right after user selects it you would need to make a proper `connect`. For example:

```
connect(box, SIGNAL(currentIndexChanged(const QString&)), this, SLOT(colorSelected(const QString&)));
```

Where `colorSelected` would be the slot where you handle the selected color value:

```
void Dialog::colorSelected(const QString& text)
{
    const QColor selected = colors[text];
    // do what you need with the color
}
```

Comment: I am getting errors when I am adding the colorMap. Can you please see where am I going wrong.

Comment: getting error as colorMap is not declared in this scope.

Comment: It should refer to the `colors` map created above. Updated the sample

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above, I'd suggest using the item data to hold the color definitions. Look at:

```
QComboBox::setItemData
QComboBox::itemData
QComboBox::currentData
```

Each item in a combo box has two components; there's the text that's displayed, and then there's a related QVariant, which is the item data. The QVariant can hold your color definition so that you don't have to store them separately. In reality, it's more than two because you could define as many user roles as you want, which would allow you to store even more data elements per combobox item. For your purposes, however, the default UserRole is sufficient.

Your colorSelected definition would be:

```
void Dialog::colorSelected (const QString &text)
{
    const QColor selected = box->currentData().value <QColor> ();
    // do what you need with the color
}
```

Comment: This would be fine as well. However, it is debatable that you would not need to store the map separately. From my point of view you still have to but maybe at a smaller scope. Remember that you still need to fill the data and `setItemData` takes only one item at a time.

Comment: Whether or not the map is needed depends on stuff we don't know. I neglected to mention the population side. One of the "addItem" overloads supports adding the text and user data at the same time, so it can actually be done in one call. Thank you for mentioning that. If you had more than one piece of user data, then you'd have to use separate calls, but this particular case is very common in my experience, so text paired with a single user data item is very often sufficient.

Comment: You are correct in the mentioned matters: we don't know stuff here, `addItem` has a proper overload and the paired text with `userData` seems to be sufficient. Nevertheless, if the data doesn't come from another method which already hands it in a kind of container (so you can loop over it and call `addItem` to set what you need) and you want to define your set of colors avoiding any additional containers, you are left with calling `addItem` multiple times. Still this is actually something the author should decide upon requirements unknown to us.

Comment: This is still drawing only 1 rectangle. how can I draw another rectangle ?

Comment: Not a surprise. Your question here was about selecting custom colors from a QComboBox. The subject of many rectangles and their selection was already answered here: [QT draw a rectangle on top of another when a button is clicked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40918951/qt-draw-a-rectangle-on-top-of-another-when-a-button-is-clicked). You need to make the logic of adding the rectangles in your `on_pushButton_clicked` method. Just keep the `QGraphicsScene` a member of the dialog instead adding new each time the slot is called.